# Software for Windows server monitoring

Tags: windows, monitoring

Can anyone recommend monitoring software for a windows environment?

We already have monitoring in the sense of resources and availability.  I want to know who logged in and changed settings, added files etc.

We have outsourced IT and I want to be able to track down all the changes to the system.

I'm open to keyboard logging or session recording.

Open Source/Free is optimal, but we're willing to pay for a solution as well.

---

#### Edit:

It looks like we don't have the Systems Admin skillset yet.

Comment: Yes.  I realize that you would use a program to do this, but it is really more a system administration question not a programming question.

Comment: If you've outsourced your IT to someone you don't trust, I'd be composing a resume.

Comment: No I trust them, but not necessarily their competence.  They use a single sign on for all their employees...  Licensing and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at zabbix www.zabbix.com.
Open source
does the utilization/resource thing, but also has customizable agents and the ability to do event notification.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, definitely take a look at EventSentry, it should be able to do most everything you want and at a reasonable price.  There is a "lite" free version as well, of course it is more limited.  And of course you know that monitoring file changes can generate extremely large volumes of audit data and take a lot of overhead...

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution you're looking for comes straight from MS: [System Center Operations Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/opsmgr/default.aspx).  It's pretty slick, but might be more (system and budget wise) than you need.

Comment: I am a big fan of SCOM personally as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few... favorites at the top...

http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/operations-manager.aspx

http://www.solarwinds.com/

http://www.whatsupgold.com/

http://www.nagios.org/

http://www.manageengine.com/datacenter-and-server-management.html

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the free service http://www.owlerts.com